# Combinatorial tree expansion due to product/quotient rule.

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

I have a binary expression tree `A` of height `n`, with `|A|` nodes.

For part 1, interior nodes can be `*` or `+`, while leaves are variables. Assume that the tree is rooted by `*`. I will take the derivative of `A` to get a tree for `A'` using recursive application of the product rule (and distributing over `+` as needed).

I need to conservatively allocate space for the result, and I am trying to come up with a closed-form expression of `n` and/or `|A|` that will provide an upper-bound `|A'|`. I'm fairly certain that `n'=2n-1`, and thus a loose upper bound for `|A'|` is just `2^{2n-1}-1`, but I was hoping I could get something tighter.

I feel like I should at least be able to figure out how many nodes are "missing" from the full binary tree, but can't quite reason how, and if I could compute a bound based on `|A|` rather than `n` that would be wonderful.

As an example, the complete binary tree below consisting of only `*` has `n=3` and `|A|=7`, while its derivative has `n'=5` and `|A'|=23`.

[image]
[image]

For part 2 I would like to extend the types in the tree to include `/` and `-`, and compute an upper bound for `n'` and `|A'|` if I extend my transformation to include the quotient rule.

Comment: Thinking about this a bit it's clear that if there are `|a|` leaves, then a fully expanded tree (i.e., distributing over `+` above) simply generates the `|a| choose 1` terms, and what I have above is the factored form of that tree. Maybe there's some way to approach this as computing the number of nodes required to factor the `|a|x|a|` identity matrix that would correspond to a truth table for these leaf cluster selections?